# Java-RS Class implements Serializable

Tags: java, rest, serialization, blob

I am using Netbeans and have created a restful webservice from database. The boiler code it has produced has implemented my blob field as serializable which causes an error.

```
IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.io.Serializable is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces
```

I just wanted some ideas to best implement this field, I know it will contain binary64 encoded data, would it be best to use a string or byte[] as the container or is there a work around to leaving it serializable?

```
public class Pothole implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Lob
@Column(name = "IMAGE")
private Serializable image; 

public Serializable getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Serializable image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JAXB and Interfaces

For interfaces other than `List` and `Map` JAXB requires that you specify the real impl class.  This can be done with the type setting on `@XmlElement`.

### Workaround

JAXB would be happy with `byte[]`.  You can also use `java.awt.Image`.  I would avoid using `String` for this.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions il go with byte[].